# Gwt doesn't work with com port rxtx

Tags: java

com2 - it's class which work with com port ( rxtx library ).
When I run my site on gwt and press on button run this function and errors:

```
public String greetServer(String input)  {


    try {
        comm2 COM = new comm2("COM3", "$KE,WR,6,1\n");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return input;



}


  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:69)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
        at com.aaa.server.comm2.<init>(comm2.java:17)
        at com.aaa.server.GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer(GreetingServiceImpl.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
        ... 34 more
```

on first run i see in error's

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.rxtxSerial)
```

Comment: You have all files correctly installed?

Comment: Why would a com-port library work on GAE?

Comment: need to turn of GAE?? then try?>

Answer (score 4):

GWT is primarily a cross compiler that translates Java code to Javascript which runs completely inside the browser. That means you cannot do anything that cannot be done inside a browser like any kind of IO or accessing COM ports

Update 1:

---

Actually after reviewing your question, it looks like your code is run on the server not the client. Your question confused me. You question should have been about executing the library  through gwt rpc on the embedded jetty or whatever.

I can see that your stacktrace lists google app engine, do you intend to run the app on app engine? If yes, then how do you intend to access the hardware? if not, you should remove the app engine dependency and run on the webserver directly.

Comment: and how it could be implemented? and server-side GWT supports any java code. Why, then, can it be implemented?

Comment: I want to get access to the hardware through my GWT application - for this I need to abandon the app engine? How do make sure that the page (server part) had access to com port?

Comment: like @AhHatem mentioned, you need to remove the GAE dependancy from your project. GAE projects are intended to be run on Google infrastructure. Google has set restrictions on Java API usage. For example, you cannot perform File IO operations. Create a Web Application Project with un-selecting "use Google App Engine" in Eclipse to remove dependancy on GAE.

Answer (score 3):

This because you don't have ALL RxTx native dependency in correct directory or path.

to avoid this error use "Neuron Robotics Java Serial Library" a RxTx fork.

Some Advantage over original RxTx

- Self deployment of native libraries ( all native code is stored inside the jar and deployed at runtime). No more manual install of native code
- A simplified serial port class called NRSerialPort to: open,read,write

Download ".Jar" from

- http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/ -

OR if you use maven, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neuronrobotics</groupId>
    <artifactId>nrjavaserial</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

check last version for maven here

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.neuronrobotics/nrjavaserial/

PS: Last version in Google-code is 3.8.4, and in mvnrepository 3.7.5.1.