# RXTX library in an applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, rxtx

I'm developing an applet that uses the RXTX library, it works fine on eclipse, but when i export the jar and embed in an html page I get

```
NoClassDefFoundError: could not initialize class gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.
```

I suppose that I don't have to include the jar in the embed tag, because it is included in the java environment extensions, but I tried it and it didn't worked, how can i solve this?

If I include the source of the RXTXcomm library or anything like that, could it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362350/gwt-doesnt-work-with-com-port-rxtx) it might help you.
As they say the error is probably you don't have ALL RxTx native dependency in the right directory or path.

Comment: Sure it does but because you have all dependency solved in your Eclipse project. When you export the jar file the native RXTX libraries are not embedded in this jar file. It doesn't matter if it's a web or swing project, you must to copy native libraries (`librxtxSerial.so` for Linux / `rxtxSerial.dll` for Windows / `librxtxSerial.jnilib` for MAC OS X) with your generated jar.

Comment: To avoid this issue you can try using [NRJavaSerial](http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/) as suggested in question I linked in my answer. Honestly I didn't try this library but I think I will soon in a project I'm working on.

Comment: The problem was that chrome uses another java installation(32bits), and i was working over my 64bits installation... very stupid

Comment: I'm happy you've solved it and easier than expected :) But please tell me how did you handle the native libraries dependency.

Comment: Just installed it in the 32bits java environment, but now i have another error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.open(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lgnu/io/RXTXPort; `

Comment: Are you using Tomcat as web server? If so [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=35919) is an interesting discussion about RXTX and Tomcat. Who started this post had the same error as you have and solved it configuring Tomcat's classpath (see answer #12 - IlanGanor » Fri Mar 08, 2013 8:23 am ). Hope it helps you!